# My dataframe has a list as an index, how do I access a cell or edit a cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, data-science

My pandas dataframe looks like this

```
                   A          B          C          D          E
(Name1, 1)         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  
(Name2, 2)         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

How do I access the a particular cell or change the value of a particular cell

I created the dataframe using this

```
id=list(product(array1,array2))
data=pd.DataFrame(index=id ,columns=array3)
```

Comment: Do you have `tuple index` or [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) ?

Comment: Not exactly, id is a list of lists: length of Array1 != Length of Array2; so product is every combination of Array 1 and Array 2 put into a list of lists =>>>[ [array1[0],array2[0]] , [array1[0],array2[1]] , [array1[1],array2[0]]  ] and so on

Comment: Ok, but I think best is use `MultiIndex` - it is very nice feature in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

```
np.random.seed(124)
array1 = np.array(['Name1','Name2'])
array2 = np.array([1,2])
array3 = np.array(list('ABCDE'))
idx= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([array1,array2])
data=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=[len(idx), len(array3)]),
                  index=idx ,columns=array3)
print (data)
         A  B  C  D  E
Name1 1  1  7  2  9  0
      2  4  4  5  5  6
Name2 1  9  6  0  8  9
      2  9  0  2  2  1

print (data.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Name1', 'Name2'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])


data.loc[('Name1', 2), 'B'] = 20
print (data)
         A  B  C  D  E
Name1 1  1  7  2  9  0
      2  4 20  5  5  6
Name2 1  9  6  0  8  9
      2  9  0  2  2  1
```

For complicated selects are used [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data.loc[idx['Name1', 2], 'B'] = 20
print (data)
         A  B  C  D  E
Name1 1  1  7  2  9  0
      2  4 20  5  5  6
Name2 1  9  6  0  8  9
      2  9  0  2  2  1

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (data.loc[idx['Name1', 2], 'A'])
4

#select all values with 2 of second level and column A
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (data.loc[idx[:, 2], 'A'])
Name1  2    4
Name2  2    9
Name: A, dtype: int32

#select 1 form second level and slice between B and D columns
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (data.loc[idx[:, 1], idx['B':'D']])
         B  C  D
Name1 1  7  2  9
Name2 1  6  0  8
```

For simplier selects use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (data.xs('Name1', axis=0, level=0))
   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  7  2  9  0
2  4  4  5  5  6
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, couldn't figure out how to use MultiIndex ( MultiIndex.from_product) so had to resort to doing what I did